# How can I fix a "not a function" JavaScript error in Firefox's console?

Tags: javascript, firefox

The code below works fine in Chrome but does not work in Firefox.  The error displayed in the Firefox console is "Error: document.forms.frmCreateNewEmployee.elements is not a function".

```
document.forms['frmCreateNewEmployee'].elements('employeeType').value = document.getElementById("userType").options[document.getElementById("userType").selectedIndex].value;
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `.elements('employeeType')` to `.elements['employeeType']` to fix the error.